# Are pharmacies/stores selling general toiletries open airside in Terminal 1, Frankfurt

Tags: transit, uk-citizens, shopping, frankfurt, toiletries

I’m due to fly Lufthansa/Condor from Manchester > Frankfurt > Holguin on 19 December, transiting airside. Does anyone know what pharmacies/stores selling general toiletries are open airside in Terminal 1? I’ve searched online but could only find fairly generic information such as https://www.airport-fra.com/services.php and as I’m not very familiar with the airport layout I’m still not sure what to hope for / expect.

I’ll be staying two months in Cuba. Due to the dire shortages there of essential toiletries such as toothpaste, shampoo, deodorant, and soap, I need to maximise the supply I take with me (both for my own use and to be able to give as much as possible to friends living there). Luggage constraints mean I can’t pack as much as I’d like to, and I’m hoping to be able to buy more during the wait for my connection.

I don’t think I can rely on being able to buy extra airside in Manchester because I assume I’ll have to clear security on arrival in Frankfurt to transfer to my onbound flight.

Edit: I’m not looking for advice on buying extra baggage allowance (not an option) or the likely higher cost of toiletries at the airport (not a concern).  It’d be good to get answers from anyone who has been airside at FRA recently.

Comment: It'd be good to get answers from folks who've been airside at FRA. Clicking through on the link in the first paragraph of your question yields a list of T1 shops and telephone numbers for each. While clothing and restaurants can be omitted from a call list, it'd still be clumsy to call each shop, find out if the shop is airside or landside, and ask the airsiders about their stock.

Comment: Do you have time to go landside ? There is a drug store (Rossman) and a super market (REWE) close to the long distance train station (Fernbahnhof). Maybe 7 minute walk from the Terminal. If there is anything airside, it will be expensive.

Comment: @Hilmar Yes I would have time, however my objective in booking this particular flight option was *not* to clear Immigration in order to minimise paperwork and the risk of not being allowed to travel at the last minute should Covid-related restrictions be tightened. I don’t mind the cost - these items have been incredibly difficult to find in Cuba for months, and their prices have rocketed as a result.

Comment: Look and see if what you want is available and order it it beforhand. [Online airport shopping? How it works | Frankfurt Airport Online Shopping](https://shop.frankfurt-airport.com/en-US/page/ordering-options): *To provide you with your reservation on time, you must enter your flight date and flight number when placing your order. ... On the day of your flight, your order will be ready for you at the service point in the Duty Free Store in flight area A*. [Area A to C are located in Terminal 1]

Comment: @Mark Johnson Thanks, I already looked at that but it doesn’t seem like ordinary basics such as toothpaste, soap etc are available to pre-order

Comment: Here you can download a map of terminal 1 that show all shops and their types. [Shops & Gastronomie](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/de/am-flughafen/shops-gastronomie.html) In one of the photos for [Metropolitan Pharmacy, Apotheke am int. Flughafen Terminal 1, Transit Z](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zc0rKhIL8wyLzdgtFI1qDAxT0oxSEw1t0w1MTdPTja1MqhIsTQyTjM3NjQzNU-ytDCw8JJJK0rMy04rLSpRSMspTc9ITEvNU0gsyC_JSM1OBQAGghor&q=frankfurt+flughafen+apotheke) I can see many toothpaste brands and they probably have soap as well.

Comment: Any airside shop selling toiletries will be the tiny size ones at premium prices. Despite the luggage constraints I recommend buying at a regular store.

Comment: @DJClayworth I’ve already done that, and would love to be able to double or even triple what I have, but after so many months of not being able to visit I have a multitude of clothes, shoes, vitamins, OTC medicines etc to take for my family there so I really can’t fit any more toiletries in my luggage without sacrificing something else equally essential :-(

Comment: @Traveller: you need to put it somewhere no matter where you buy it. Consider buying extra baggage allowance. That's probably cheaper than airside prices and you don't need to stuff it in your backpack or pockets.

Comment: @Hilmar I can put it in my carry on (can’t do that before arriving in Frankfurt because I assume I’ll have to clear security there to transfer to my connecting flight). I already have the maximum baggage allowance for the route, buying more isn’t an option.

Comment: @Mark Johnson Metropolitan Pharmacy looks like an answer, thank you https://www.tripability.net/admin/resources/fraport-airport.pdf

Comment: @Traveller I would not count on that. German pharmacies usually sell medicines and medical products and not toiletries. You might find specialized products, like e.g. anti-dandruff shampoos or different kinds of medical toothpaste, but not the generic and common products I would assume that you are looking for.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Since this is **not** a usual German pharmacy, but one situated within an airport transit area (and thus likely to serve the needs of the average traveler). The 2 brands I recognised in their image can be bought almost anywhere. Had you made the effort to look at the images (as I did before making the comment) you would have seen that. But you obviously preferred not to do so, but instead made a misleading comment that ignores the given situation of this question.

Comment: Is it possible to take any amount of showering gel into the plane, when bought in the transit area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what pharmacies/stores selling general toiletries are open airside in Terminal 1?

You can download a map of terminal 1 that show all shops and their types.
[Shops & Gastronomie](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/de/am-flughafen/shops-gastronomie.html)

- [Aktueller Shopping & Dining Guide für das Terminal 1](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/dam/fraport-travel/airport/dokumente/am-flughafen/shopping-dining-guide/FRA_SD-Guide_T1_03_2021.pdf/_jcr_content/renditions/original./FRA_SD-Guide_T1_03_2021.pdf) (PDF)
- [Aktueller Shopping & Dining Guide für das Terminal 2](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/dam/fraport-travel/airport/dokumente/am-flughafen/shopping-dining-guide/FRAPORT_Bereichspl%C3%A4ne_T2_bearbeitet_04.3_X4_Ansicht_CI_Schrift.pdf/_jcr_content/renditions/original./FRAPORT_Bereichspl%C3%A4ne_T2_bearbeitet_04.3_X4_Ansicht_CI_Schrift.pdf) (PDF)

> essential toiletries such as toothpaste, shampoo, deodorant, and soap

In one of the photos for [Metropolitan Pharmacy, Apotheke am int. Flughafen Terminal 1, Transit Z](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zc0rKhIL8wyLzdgtFI1qDAxT0oxSEw1t0w1MTdPTja1MqhIsTQyTjM3NjQzNU-ytDCw8JJJK0rMy04rLSpRSMspTc9ITEvNU0gsyC_JSM1OBQAGghor&q=frankfurt+flughafen+apotheke) I can see many toothpaste brands and they probably have soap as well.

[image]
Ajona (25ml, middle shelf, right) and Parodontax (75ml, lower shelf, center) are 2 brands that I recognise and are also available in drugeries and well stocked grocery stores.

**Ajona** is good for traveling since it small, but plentyfull due to the small portion needed. (normal cost between € 1.25-€1.35)

> Ajona is a medical TOOTHCREAM CONCENTRATE and **about five times more economical than normal toothpaste**.  Please use sparingly - a lentil-sized amount is sufficient.

---

Other, more specialised, products can be ordered beforehand and picked up based on your given flight date and flight number:
[Online airport shopping? How it works | Frankfurt Airport Online Shopping](https://shop.frankfurt-airport.com/en-US/page/ordering-options): *To provide you with your reservation on time, you must enter your flight date and flight number when placing your order. ... On the day of your flight, your order will be ready for you at the service point in the Duty Free Store in flight area A*. [Area A to C are located in Terminal 1]

Comment: Ajona does not contain Fluoride - if you care.